# What is the common design pattern of Event Handlers in Windows form

Tags: winforms, design-patterns, event-handling

i would like to know what is the correct way to define an Event Handler in WinForm. I'm asking this because i have one application in where only some event handlers has logic inside, others only make calls to methods defined elsewhere. Is this fine?, i'm a little worried because maybe is a bad design that in a given moment its going to give me troubles. Having event handlers with intensive logic inside is a bad pattern?

Comment: This is the intended design. Windows is an event-driven environment. The only possible place you have to execute code is in response to user-initiated events. It's not an inherently bad pattern. There are alternatives, but it's impossible (and premature) to make reasonable suggestions without knowing more about the specific logic you're executing.

Answer (score 1):

There are in general no restrictions on what you do in a Winforms event handler.  But it has side-effects that are easy to see for yourself, if you do a lot of work then the user interface goes catatonic.  It no longer responds to mouse clicks, it doesn't repaint itself anymore.  After about 3 seconds, Windows replaces the form with the ghost window with "Not Responding" in the title bar.

You'd have to write a great deal of code to trigger that condition, one second is over 4 *billion* machine instructions.  The typical UI freeze is caused by waiting for something else to get the job done, a dbase query for example.

That is ugly and doesn't make a great impression.  And can make it uncomfortable to use your user interface.  Nothing very pretty about a user banging away on a button that doesn't respond.  You'd use a work threader to solve this problem, BackGroundWorker is made for that.  This is not so easy to get right, only use this if you have a real problem to solve.  Don't assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

Complicated logic of an event handler is bad in some cases but not always.  Typically bad thing would be to do a lot of work in a handler to cell repaint of a datagrid or similar that would cause gui to flicker.  You can make such handlers asynchronous. 
Calling other methods from event handlers is ok as long as you defend agains crossthreadedoperationexceptions.
However, you must consider your architecture needs and jump from there.

Answer (score 0):

> > Having event handlers with intensive logic inside is a bad pattern?

If you are asking this question yourself: Yes. There might be some exceptions, but too much code inside UI-eventhandlers is often a mark of bad design.

You should take a look at MVP (both MVP-Passive View and MVP-Supervising controller) and maybe even MVVM and MVC. Those are the most "famous" design patterns to seperate the logic from the presentation.  
Personally, I prefer MVP-Passive View in WinForms but there are many opinions on that.